# Set-Cookie sent by express-sessions is not being set on browser but works in local development

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-cookies, vercel

I have a nextjs 13 app that is currently hosted on Vercel, and a node.js express backend

I am using express-sessions with google oauth flow, however the set-cookie sent by express-sessions is not being set on the browser.

The flow is as follows:

1. Nextjs app requests google auth uri, backend responds with the auth uri
2. Redirect to the google auth uri
3. On successful login, it redirects to a route on nextjs app which redirects to the backend (such that the query params are still part of the url
4. The backend processes the query params, and stores information on the `req.session`, and redirects again to the nextjs app with `set-cookie`

Here is the response sent by the backend:

[image]

[image]

Setup of the express-sessions middleware:

```
app.use(
    session({
        name: 'sessionID',
        cookie: {
            maxAge: SESSION_LIFETIME as number,
            sameSite: 'lax',
            secure: NODE_ENV === 'production',
            httpOnly: true
        },
        resave: false,
        secret: SESSION_SECRET as string,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: redisStore
    })
);
```

Google OAuth Callback Code:

```js
    try {
        const query = url.parse(request.url, true).query as {
            code: string;
        };

        const { tokens } = await googleOauth.getToken(query.code);
        const { access_token, refresh_token } = tokens;
        const userInfoResponse = await fetch(
            `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=${access_token}`
        );

        const { email } = await userInfoResponse.json();

        let user = await getUserByEmail(email);

        if (user === undefined) {
            response.writeHead(307, { Location: process.env.WEB_URL + '?error=failed' });
            response.end();
            return;
        }

        // If it's the first time user logged in, create an account
        if (user === null) {
            user = await createUser({ email });

            // Something went wrong when creating the user
            if (!user) {
                response.writeHead(307, { Location: process.env.WEB_URL + '?error=failed' });
                response.end();
                return;
            }
        }

        const userToken = await saveUserTokens(
            user.id,
            access_token as string,
            refresh_token as string,
            OAuthProvider.google
        );

        if (!userToken) {
            response.writeHead(307, { Location: process.env.WEB_URL + '/?error=true' });
            response.end();
            return;
        }

        request.session.userId = user.id.toString();
        response.redirect(307, process.env.WEB_URL as string);

    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error while logging in with google', error);

        response.writeHead(307, { Location: process.env.WEB_URL + '/?error=true' });
        response.end();
    }
```

I think this may be due several redirects happening? I have another endpoint for authentication using email and password with express-sessions, and set-cookie sent by that response is set successfully. Here is the response for the /login route for email and password authentication:

[image]
[image]

Login handler (email + pass) code:

```
const loginHandler: RequestHandler = async (request, response) => {
    const { email, password } = request.body;

    const isValid = is(email, Email) && is(password, Password);

    if (!isValid) {
        return response
            .status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
            .send({ message: 'Invalid Request: Missing or invalid email and password.' });
    }

    const user = await getUserByEmail(email);

    if (!user) {
        return response.sendStatus(401);
    }

    // Check if user logged in previously with another provider
    if (!user.password) {
        return response
            .status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
            .send({ message: 'Please login with the login provider you used previously' });
    }

    const isPasswordCorrect = await compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
        return response.sendStatus(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    request.session.userId = user.id.toString();

    response.sendStatus(StatusCodes.OK);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if your frontend and backend are separate domaine try to set your cookie again like this :

```
app.use(
    session({
        name: 'sessionID',
        cookie: {
            maxAge: SESSION_LIFETIME as number,
            sameSite: 'none', // in order to response to both first-party and cross-site requests
            secure: 'auto', // it should set automatically to secure if is https.
            httpOnly: true
        },
        resave: false,
        secret: SESSION_SECRET as string,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: redisStore
    })
);
```

Comment: Frontend and backend are on the same domain, and this doesn't seem to be reason for the problem because I think if the configuration was the issue then the /login route would also not work

Comment: which browser have you test?  did you try several one to check if you got the same issue

Comment: Yea, this issue persists on Chrome, Firefox & Safari so I think all browsers

Comment: Well the cookie is set successfully on the browser, but it looks like your request header didn't attach it properly on your 1st screenshot, have you try to add option on your fetch on the header something like {Authorization : `Bearer ${access_token}` but don't see all the code so not sure about it.